# Checking the ID already exists in the array, after inputing from a form

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Had an Array, have an update Array function, input will be taken through Form.
**Upon Input of ID,I want to check if the ID already exist in the array**

**Have given input as 1 ,which should give true.**

## It is showing "false" in console.

```
  const bioData = [
    {id:1}
   ]

const [myArray, setmyArray] = useState(bioData);
const [sid, setId] = useState("");
const handleID = (e) => {
  setId(e.target.value);
}
const updateArray = () =>{
 
 
  const isFound = myArray.some(el => el.id === sid);

  console.log(isFound);

  if (isFound) {
    console.log('✅ array contains object with id = 1');
  }
}

<input type="number" placeholder='Please enter your ID' className='inputelm' onChange={handleID} />
<button className='addbtn btn inputelm' onClick={updateArray}>Add</button>
```

Comment: When do you call `updateArray`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The useState set method is not reflecting a change immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/the-usestate-set-method-is-not-reflecting-a-change-immediately)

Comment: What does `myArray` or `sid` contain when this code is executed?  If a match is not found then it's not found.  The various React bits surrounding this operation are either (1) irrelevant and just a distraction or (2) an important part of the observed result and incomplete in the question.  I'm thinking it's likely the latter.  Can you provide a runnable [mcve] which demonstrates the problem?

Comment: Have Updated check once

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Your post doesn't match the standards StackOverflow sets. Please read this guide: [How To: Ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Also your issue is in the `updateArray` method. You are trying to access `fname` and `score` however they are not defined. So you need to define them. ALso you should update the state of `myArray` with the new data you get.

Comment: Have Updated Please read the Questions again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is showing false because `bioData[0].id` is a number but what you get from `input_id.value` is a string. Input elements always return a string, even for `type="number"`. type attribute is just there for ease of input, it does not parse data in any way. either use `parseInt()` when getting the value from input or change the **Initial_data** to contain id as a string.

```
//Filename: App.js

import { useState, useRef } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const bioData = [{ id: 1, name: "harry", score: 12 }];
  const [myArray, setMyArray] = useState(bioData);
  const [sid, setId] = useState();
  const nameInput = useRef();
  const scoreInput = useRef();

  const handleId = (e) => {
//parseInt(value, radix)
//for decimal number system, radix is 10 
    setId(parseInt(e.target.value, 10));
  };

  const updateArray = () => {
    const new_data = {
      id: sid,
      name: nameInput.current.value,
      score: scoreInput.current.value
    };

    const isFound = myArray.some((el) => {
      return el.id === new_data.id;
    });

    if (isFound) {
      console.log("✅ array contains object with id:", new_data.id);
      return;
    }
    setMyArray([...myArray, new_data]);
    console.log("updated");
  };

  return (
    <form>
      <input
        ref={nameInput}
        type="number"
        placeholder="Enter Id"
        onChange={(e) => handleId(e)}
        required
      />
      <input ref={scoreInput} type="text" placeholder="Enter Name" required />
      <input
        id="input-score"
        type="number"
        placeholder="Enter Score"
        required
      />
      <button
        type="submit"
        onClick={(e) => {
          e.preventDefault();
          updateArray();
        }}
      >
        submit
      </button>
    </form>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For this you should write the given code

```
const isFound = myArray.some(el => el._id === sid);
```

instead of

```
const isFound = myArray.some(el => el.id === sid);
```

because the mongodb has the id of the element as _id.

Comment: Maybe I missed something, but where do they say they are using mongodb? There are no references to `_id in their code.

Comment: he is using the database so i think that will be the reason

Comment: The point doesn't mention a database. What leads you to this conclusion?